# Org mode export with R failing

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I have an org file with R code in it. When I attempt to export to html or pdf I get an error:

For example if my file was:

```
#+begin_src R :exports code
square <- function(x) 
{
 x * x
}

square(1:10)
#+end_src
```

I type: `C-c C-e h o` the mini buffer says: `Symbol’s value as variable is void: backend`

Comment: And if you change the language to something other then R it works?

Comment: yes emacs lisp works for example

Comment: What major mode are you using for R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had this line in my `.emacs` but I added another copy at the end of the `.emacs` file and it solved the problem. So maybe there is an ordering constraint for this to work correctly.

`(require 'ess-site)`